# magento 2.3 render admin panel attribute on product page under Description tag

Tags: product-attribute, product-page, magento2.3.1

I have 4-5 features attributes as feature_1, feature_2 etc in admin for products. I have set their configuration of 'Visible on Catalog Pages Storefront view' as yes. 
I want to render features of products for which they conatin values on product page under Description tab . 
How can I do this ?